# Mouse picks up drag-and-drop items on single click

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, kde

I've been having a problem for some time now where my mouse will pick up drag-and-drop items such as browser-tabs, images or files when I simply click on them.

So in long: If I simply click on a browser tab the mouse will quite often pick it up as if I was holding the button. I then have to place it back where it belongs by clicking again. It only happens when the cursor is still moving the last few pixel "during" the click, as it often happens when you quickly select a tab. If I simply hover the cursor over the tab, no amount of clicking recreates the problem.

I have tried:

- two browsers: Vivaldi and Firefox
- two mice, both in each browser
- the event-checker: Both mice seem to function as they should

And the problem is the same every time.

This leads me to believe that the problem is not specifically a browser or hardware issue, but somewhere in my OS settings.

I am using:

- Kubuntu 20.04
- KDE Plasma Version 5.18.5
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
- QT Version 5.12.8
- Kernel Version 5.8.0.050800-generic

I cannot find anything in the system settings that would fix it though. I would be very glad for pointers to what else to look for!

Edit: Oddly enough, Vivaldi's recent 3.5 update changed something about its tabs and this problem no longer occurs there. That takes away almost all of my annoyance. The problem still occurs in Firefox and occasionally when my mouse randomly picks up other drag-and-drop items like images or files.